# iOS native library

Tags: visual-studio-2015, xamarin.ios

I am using visual studio 2015 and I have created a native library and added objective C library "airconsolelib.a".
as well as using Sharpie I have also created ApiDefinition.cs and StructsAndEnums.cs.

issue is when I am adding this project to my iOS project I am not able to access any namespace and classes of my native library.

please help

Comment: Was the binding library created in Xamarin Studio or Visual Studio?

Comment: library created  in visual studio 2015

Comment: Try creating the library in XS and copy over to VS the generated dll to see if that works

Comment: sure I will do that

Comment: can you please also help me on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42713531/ios-corebluetooth-data-send-issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is related to visual studio.
Visual studio in not showing any intelligence related to native library,
even if I am writing the name of a class or adding namespace its showing red line below it but when I am compiling the code there is no error.